# SSRS Multi Value Matrix Field

Tags: reporting-services, matrix, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix

I have the data as follows:

```
WEEK    WEEK_DAY    DAY_NAME    DATE        RECORD
1              4    Wednesday   2014-01-01  NULL
1              5    Thursday    2014-01-02  IM13368
1              5    Thursday    2014-01-02  IM13377
1              6    Friday      2014-01-03  IM13381
1              6    Friday      2014-01-03  IM13364
1              7    Saturday    2014-01-04  NULL
```

Now I want the data represent with Matrix report via SSRS (Calendar-like), but if there are two or more values for the same week and weekday, the matrix's field shows only one value, not all of them.

How can I force the report to show all of them in the specific day?

Comment: So for `2014-01-02` what do you want to see?

Answer (score 0):

You have to click the matrix and select HideDuplicates to None. Like in the image below:

[image]

Maybe [this topic](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/171e4e3a-1bee-4c3e-98b1-ef1b4bc3c374/hide-duplicate-row-ssrs-2008-r2?forum=sqlreportingservices) might help you:

as well as [this other one](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Database/MS-SQL-Server/MS-SQL_Reporting/Q_24825313.html).